# configure git in pycharm through WSL

Tags: python-3.x, git, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It seems like something went wrong when I set git inside pycharm like this:

[image]

my git installed inside WSL is version-2.17.1; pycharm is professional version

Comment: I think for git you need to give it a path to the git that is installed on windows itself.

Comment: Did you run pycharm as admin?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I wonder if there is a way for pycharm to use git inside subsystem

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly invoke Linux programs from a Win32 program like this.  You may have better luck creating a batch file that invokes the `wsl` binary and use that.  Something like the following in the batch file may be useful:

```
wsl git %*
```

Then invoke your batch file as the Git binary.

Do note that your Linux Git binary will expect Unix paths, not Win32 paths, so if you can't guarantee that Unix paths will be passed, you'll need to either switch both your editor and Git to be Linux programs, switch them both to be Windows programs, or not use Git inside your editor.